# Google Analytics not working in Android webviews

Tags: javascript, android, webview, google-analytics

I a webview in my Android app to display my own custom ad network. I've tried adding Google Analytics to this webview's page both with the ga.js and analytics.js. With either library, it will *not* record users visiting the page in Google Analytics. However, if I open Chrome on Android and go directly to the page, then I can see myself in the real-time analytics stats. Am I missing something to get this to work with webviews?

Here's what I've tried with both methods:

ga.js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var _gaq = _gaq || [];
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXX-6']);
        _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'none']);
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

        (function () {
            var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
            ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
        })();

    </script>
```

and analytics.js:

```
<script>
    (function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
        i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r; i[r] = i[r] || function () {
            (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
        }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date(); a = s.createElement(o),
        m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0]; a.async = 1; a.src = g; m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
    })(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-5', 'none');
    ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

I've tested this against a Nexus 5 (4.4.2) and Galaxy Nexus (4.2.2). The ads are also live, so it isn't reporting any of my users either (I know there are quite a few users hitting the page at any given time).

Android webview:

```
<WebView
            android:id="@+id/ad"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
        />

 WebView adView;
 adView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.ad);

 // Setup handler for 404's
adView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() 
{
    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) 
    {
        div_ads.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) 
    {
        try
        { 
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(i);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

            Toast.makeText(RadioReddit.this, "Web Browser Error: Application is not installed on your phone", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    return true;

    }

 });


// Request an ad
adView.loadUrl("http://www.urltomyads.com/default.aspx?id=" + applicationID);
```

Comment: Post your webview/webviewclient code.

Comment: @MorrisonChang Added, but there's nothing special about it. It just loads a URL and when you click it, it opens the browser to the URL of the ad's image on the web page.

Comment: WebSettings code? I assume if you are running Javascript you've enabled setJavaScriptEnabled(true)

Comment: @MorrisonChang Argh, let me guess, javascript is set to disabled by default? That's probably the issue.

Comment: If that was the issue - you can delete this question

Comment: Was that your issue? I have the same problem, but JS is enabled

Comment: Using latest WebView and GA not working with all fancy page functionality enabled. Any ideas appreciated. Perhaps cookies need to be set somehow?